# All citizens in a city geolocation dataset

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, uses-of-open-data

I am building a demo dashboard for an app that tracks the location of everyone's phones in anonymized manner to evaluate traffic, crowding dynamics and so one. For my demo I would want to have a sample dataset for a big city, e.g. New York with pinpoints (location lat. and long.) for each person in the city. Are you aware of some similar open datasets which I can use in my app?